# Getting key value pair array in Yii2

Tags: yii2

```
$data = User::find()
    ->select('id, name')
    ->where(['status' => 'active'])
    ->orderBy('id DESC')
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
[
 [0]=>[
        id=>1
        name="test"
      ]
[1]=>[
        id=>2
        name="test1"
      ]
]
```

What I want is array which looks similar to this. Mapping the id with name so it can be accessed and checked.

```
[
[1]=>'test'
[2]=>'test1'
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this
Add the below namespace and use the arrayhelper of Yii2 to map

```
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper

$userdata = ArrayHelper::map($data, 'id', 'name');
```

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using the ArrayHelper you can directly achieve the desired output by using `indexBy()` and `column()` within your query:

```
$data = User::find()
    ->select(['name', 'id'])
    ->where(['status' => 'active'])
    ->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])
    ->indexBy('id')
    ->column();
```

[indexBy()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequeryinterface#indexBy()-detail) defines the array key, while [column()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#column()-detail) will take the first column in the select condition as value.

Comment: This does not work for numerical fields, such as `id` being a INTEGER. For indexing by text fields, such as a `key` field, this does work as expected.

When numerical fields are used, the resulting array will be re-indexed, starting with 0. The ArrayHelper solution as proposed by @Vivek does work in both situations.

Comment: What does your example look like? I don't think this is true, i just made a little test. Id is an integer value and title a string: `Example::find()->select(['title', 'id'])->indexBy('id')->column()` works perfect.

array(2) {
  [33]=>
  string(8) "title1"
  [47]=>
  string(9) "title2"
}

Comment: **A hint**: need to set "id" as second param in select() as in the example above ```->select(['name', 'id'])```.  At first I use vice versa and it not working array returned as ```["id" => "id"]```

Comment: @Lysak the former selected column will be used as value for column(). If you need id => id, then don't even select another column. https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#column()-detail